# Does prefixing system or general table names with "Sys" fine in Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, schema, database-administration

In Sql Server there's sys Schema. `sys.Columns`, `sys.Tables`.
I have a general tables which I need to rename to SysUsers, SysRoles, etc.

Is it fine to do that? I will not use Sys schema. I just will prefix tables with **Sys**
I find SQL Server itself do it generally

```
select * FROM SysColumns      // NOTE its not sys.Columns
```

Comment: Allowed? Yes. Confusing? Yes. Good Idea? No. Opinion-based? Yes. You decide.

Comment: If you can predict the possibility of confusion, it's probably a poor choice. These will appear to be system tables, but not the DBMS system tables. Why not just avoid the potentional confusion with a more explicit naming convention?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### TL;DR: Don't do this.

You will have name clashes and your objects will be unusable.

---

I **strongly** recommend against this. If you have any objects where the names clashes you *will not* be able to reference it.

Take this simple example:

```sql
USE master;
GO

CREATE DATABASE Sillytest;
GO

USE Sillytest;
GO

SELECT *
FROM syscolumns; 
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.syscolumns; 
GO
SELECT *
FROM sys.syscolumns; 

GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.syscolumns (ID int, ColumnName sysname);
GO

SELECT *
FROM syscolumns; 
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.syscolumns; 
GO
SELECT *
FROM sys.syscolumns; 
GO

USE master;
GO

DROP DATABASE Sillytest;
GO
```

Every single reference to `syscolumns`, whether prefixed by `dbo`, `sys`, or not at all, references the object `sys.syscolumns`. Not one of those statements returns data from the (empty) user table I created `dbo.syscolumns`. Notice, as well, that the reference to `dbo.syscolumns` before I create a table of that name also works.

Yes, you can create the objects, but if the name already exists as a `sys.sys{object}` object, then you won't be able to use it.

Further to this, there is already an object [`sys.sysusers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysusers-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), so we actually have the answer; don't do it, you already have a clash.

Answer (score 0):

Total agreement with @Larnu and I upvoted that answer. Let me add one more.

By putting a single prefix at the front of all your table names, you actually hurt your ability to search, sort, and filter, your tables. It will slow down the database. It will hurt SSMS behavior and 3rd party tools.

Don't do this, but also, don't do it with something else either; tbl, tab, none of that junk.