# Need help figuring out the cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-cursor

Upd:
Thanks everyone for your answers. I appreciate it a lot.
Few points to add :

1. I replaced the actual package name to '%%' as i dont wan't to get in trouble with NDA related stuff, so i chose to be extra cautious.
2. I do use select @sql to see the query that is executed, but thanks for noticing that :)
3. Thanks again everyone for your answers.

this is my first post so it may be a little underwhelming :D

I wrote this script to help me delete data with all dependencies it has at once, but there are two issues i have :

```
declare @PackageId uniqueidentifier ;
set @PackageId = (select Id from SysPackage where name like '%%');
declare @tableName varchar(max);
declare @Columnname varchar(max);
declare @sql varchar(max);
declare dependent_tables Cursor 
FOR SELECT  
    tab1.name,
    col1.name
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
INNER JOIN sys.objects obj
    ON obj.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables tab1
    ON tab1.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sch
    ON tab1.schema_id = sch.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns col1
    ON col1.column_id = parent_column_id AND col1.object_id = tab1.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables tab2
    ON tab2.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns col2
    ON col2.column_id = referenced_column_id AND col2.object_id = tab2.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_keys fk
    ON fk.name = obj.name
where tab2.name ='SysPackage'

Open dependent_tables

Fetch NEXT from dependent_tables INTO
    @tableName, 
    @columnName; 

WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0 
Begin
    if @tableName is null Break;
    if @Columnname is null Break;
    set @sql=CONCAT('delete from ',@tableName,' WHERE ',@columnName,' = ',@PackageId); 
    exec (@sql); 
END;


Deallocate dependent_tables;
```

So there are basically two issues I have with this.

1. The loop is infinite, as the cursor doesn't actually loops through the records, but always stays on the same @tableName and @columName
2. There is also an issue with @packageId, which is being inserted into the query without the quotes, so the query looks like this :

   delete from Table1 where column1 =  A5664658-26D5-4600-862A-86467FD59244

I thought of creating an extra parameter to contact, kind of like this :

```
set @sql=CONCAT('delete from ',@tableName,' WHERE ',@columnName,' = ', ''',@PackageId, ''');
```

But it won't let me escape the '.
Any ideas how to figure out the way to fix it would be much much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You are not fetching the next cursor

Comment: As @Nathan_Sav, pointed out you need "Fetch NEXT from dependent_tables INTO ......" at the end of your while loop, just before the `END` keyword. For your second point you need to enter it as `' = ','''' + @PackageId + '''');`. Final comment: when developing dynamic SQL queries `PRINT` statement (e.g. `PRINT @sql`) is your single best friend. Without it you are deaf, dumb and blind. Always "print" generated query and try to run it directly in SSMS to catch trivial errors.

Comment: And close the cursor too.

Answer (score 1):

A few tips here. Firstly, use appropriate data types. An object's name can't be up for 2 Billion ANSI characters; it's name is stored as a `sysname` (a synonym for `nvarchar(128) NOT NULL`).

For your dynamic statement, don't inject parameters *parametrise* them. Don't inject raw object names either, delimit identify them (with `QUOTENAME`).

You should also *always* schema qualify your objects.

Also, I know you have a table called `SysPackage`. This is a bad idea; `sys` is a prefix already used by Microsoft. Have a read of [Does prefixing system or general table names with "Sys" fine in Sql Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70184373/does-prefixing-system-or-general-table-names-with-sys-fine-in-sql-server/70184558#70184558).

I note, as well, that your subquery, `(SELECT Id FROM dbo.SysPackage WHERE name LIKE '%%')` is effectively `WHERE Name IS NOT NULL`. I also *doubt* that query returns a single value, so I suspect that is another problem you need to address.

All of this gives you something like this:

```sql
DECLARE @PackageId uniqueidentifier;
SET @PackageId = (SELECT Id FROM dbo.SysPackage WHERE name IS NOT NULL); -- LIKE '%%' is odd. Just check if the value isn't NULL
DECLARE @SchemaName sysname; 
DECLARE @TableName sysname; --Use an appropriate data type
DECLARE @ColumnName sysname;  --Use an appropriate data type
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX); --SQL is an nvarchar, not a varchar
DECLARE dependent_tables CURSOR FOR
    SELECT sch.[name], --Ensure you schema qualify
           tab1.[name],
           col1.[name]
    FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
         INNER JOIN sys.objects obj ON obj.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
         INNER JOIN sys.tables tab1 ON tab1.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
         INNER JOIN sys.schemas sch ON tab1.schema_id = sch.schema_id
         INNER JOIN sys.columns col1 ON col1.column_id = parent_column_id
                                    AND col1.object_id = tab1.object_id
         INNER JOIN sys.tables tab2 ON tab2.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id
         INNER JOIN sys.columns col2 ON col2.column_id = referenced_column_id
                                    AND col2.object_id = tab2.object_id
         INNER JOIN sys.foreign_keys fk ON fk.name = obj.name
    WHERE tab2.name = 'SysPackage';

OPEN dependent_tables;

FETCH NEXT FROM dependent_tables
INTO @SchemaName,
     @tableName,
     @Columnname;

WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
BEGIN

    SET @sql = CONCAT(N'DELETE FROM ', QUOTENAME(@SchemaName), N'.', QUOTENAME(@TableName), N' WHERE ', QUOTENAME(@Columnname), N' = @PackageId');
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@PackageId uniqueidentifier', @PackageId;

    FETCH NEXT FROM dependent_tables
    INTO @SchemaName,
         @TableName,
         @Columnname;
END;


DEALLOCATE dependent_tables;
CLOSE dependent_tables;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the following code. You forgot to fetch data within your WHILE loop.

```
WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0 
Begin
    if @tableName is null Break;
    if @Columnname is null Break;
    set @sql=CONCAT('delete from ',@tableName,' WHERE ',@columnName,' = ',@PackageId); 
    exec (@sql); 

    FETCH NEXT FROM dependent_tables INTO 
    @tableName, 
    @columnName;  
END;
```